# Prompt user to continue in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

In Jenkins I can prompt the user to continue or cancel with the "input" directive in the pipeline definition.

Does Azure DevOps pipelines have this functionality or anything similar?

I am using a yaml file for the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Not in build definitions, no. In release definitions you can add a Serverless phase and put a Manual Intervention task.

Honestly, I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want a manual intervention in the middle of a build.

Comment: You can't use yaml for release pipelines yet. The idea that Build is a separate pipeline to Release is a bit ridiculous tbh.

Comment: where I work, we had users enter a value to a parameter when kicking of the prod pipeline. It only served as a way to prevent users from mistakenly deploying to prod. It was as simple as (if myvar == "abc"). This wasnt on Az Devops though